# FFmpeg not delaying audio properly

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

If I use the following command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i audio.avi -itsoffset 3.0 -i audio.avi -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy sync.avi
```

the audio starts to play beginning at one second instead of three seconds. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FFmpeg does not support writing stream delay in AVIs. Use MP4.

Comment: @Gyan Thanks, if you make that an answer then I'll mark it as accepted. What lossless format can I apply a delay to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVIs have an attribute dwStart to delay a stream but ffmpeg at present fixes that to 0.

Remux to MP4 where ffmpeg will write an editlist to implement it. Players like WMP which don't seem to parse the edit list won't effect the delay.

```
ffmpeg -i audio.avi -itsoffset 3.0 -i audio.avi -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy sync.mp4
```

As long as you streamcopy the input contents, any target will be lossless with respect to the source.

Comment: Thanks for not only explaining why this issue was occurring, but also giving a work-around and explaining why that work-around works. This was enlightening and immensely helpful.